# Magento 1.8.1 Missing css styles after upgrading from 1.7

Tags: css, magento

I used FTP to upgrade magento because I am not technical enough to use SSH.

First I encountered the 500 internal server error, and then the blank page googlecheckout error. Upon fixing that now I’m facing the missing stylesheet issue.

From the naked page it looked like magento is running on 1.8.1, but both frontend and backend are missing the stylesheets. On the view source's link the css path directs to a 404.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mydomainname.com/media/css/aa5d6dfa090eec7ba8c2982f89737fca.css" />
```

Please share if you know how to solve this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the URL of CSS files that give you 404 for a trailing slash just after the domain name

```
http://www.yourdomainname.comskin/frontend/default/default/css/reset.css
```

should ideally be

```
http://www.yourdomainname.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/reset.css
```

if you have the same problem then edit table **core_config_data** in your database, change values for path **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** to

```
http://www.yourdomainname.com/
```

PS: Notice the trailing slash

Comment: Hi the path to my css is `http://yourdomainname.com/media/css/0d292f325e30d8d31402ad609e1c0204.css`
and from the FTP I've checked that the css file is valid

Comment: Can you provide the actual URL of the page where you get this error.

Comment: Please clear cache from Magento Backend also try disabling 

System->Congiguration->Developer->Css Settings

Comment: Yeap tried that too but still the same. I wondered what am I missing!